# How to get user agent type from $_SERVER php

Tags: php

I know how to get user agent  from  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; But how to get only the user agent type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_browser()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) is probably what you want, — Tells what the user's browser is capable of

Usage:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);

//echo browser
echo $browser['browser'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That really helped me, but is there a example to get  the user agent type as a variable in php ?

Comment: What do you mean by user agent type? Do mean like firefox/Chrome etc?

Comment: I want to get the info like PC/SP/MB from the user agent

Comment: $browser['platform'] ?